# Java+JSP: Query String handling

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, query-string

How the best way to handle query strings in Java JSP?

The method `request.getQueryString()` returns only a strings, how can I get the value of a specific string? Should I parse that string?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
request.getParameter("param-name");
```

if query string is like

```
id=12&name=abc
```

to get `name` you can do this

```
request.getParameter("name");
```

Comment: could you please tell me how i can instantiate this `request` object in my bean?

Comment: @Shredder  request object is created by underlying container , we don't create it.. you can access it from bean depending on the framework. what exact bean you are talking about ?

Comment: I'm using jsf 1.1. I have a parts.jsp page with a managed parts.java bean and I'm trying to get the query string in parts.java. This is probably totally different than what this question relates too, i should ask a new question

Comment: If you would like to check out my question go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339397/how-can-i-get-the-query-string
:)